# how to add control button on RichTextEditor

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I'd like to custom RichTextEditor with adding a new button on control bar.
But, I don't found how to do that.

As is a mx component, skinclass is not possible, so how to do?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Home / Using Flex / Building the user interface / MX text controls / MX RichTextEditor control

Section "Add a new subcontrol"

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d89.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63fd7-7fd9